# Does there exist an initial arrangement of 10 black squares such that all the squares will ultimately be black?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, invariance

> Let there be a $12×12$ table of white squares. We draw $10$ squares in black. If a white square has $2$ black neighbours, then we draw it in black. We say that $2$ squares are neighbours if they have a common edge.

Does there exist an arrangement of the $10$ black squares such that all the squares will ultimately be black?

My intuition says that it's impossible. I divided the table into 9 $4×4$ squares and tried to use the Pigeonhole Principle, but I am stuck.

Comment: Do you iterate this process? Because if you just apply it once, at most $40$ squares are adjacent to even just one black square, let alone two, so you certainly won't get $144$ black ones. Also, do you mean at least $2$ black neighbours or exactly two black neighbours?

Comment: @joriki At least two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $P$ be a perimeter of area colored black.

We see that $P\leq 40$ at the begining and that at each step it does not increase*.

So since the whole table has perimeter $48$ it is impossible.

---

*Since each square has $4$ sides and at least $2$ sides are also sides of two neighbour black cells we must delete these two but we can add at most $2$ others.

[image]

Comment: Why don't increase at each step?

Comment: That is very neat!

Comment: Superb... analysis by quantities that remain constant over different iterations is one of the best methods of solving such problems