# Stopping the Coronavirus puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> A square region $2020 \times 2020 \text{ km}^2$ divided into $2020^2$ cells. Some cells are contaminated by *covid-19*. Every week the virus spread to those cell which have at least $2$ side in common with contaminated cells. Find the maximum number of contaminated cells such that no matter where they are located the *covid-19* pandemic will not spread to the entire region.

My school friend gave me this problem( better to say a puzzle) may be during the lockdown period(July-August) but I forgot it and yesterday he asked me if I have been able to solve the problem or not? And then the answer was obviously not, although I put a sufficient effort behind the problem that time and after the meet yesterday and also today I gave a lots of time but unable to figure it out. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: If you fill in the diagonal, the virus will spread to the entire square, so 2019 is an upper bound.  This bound appears to be tight for small $n$, but not sure in general.

Comment: Single cells and adjacent cells die, but as Daniel says, the only way to propogate is diagonal cells, which will propogate to fill entire square.  Feels like the game of Life.

Comment: Hint: if you can enclose all infected squares in a single big rectangle, no square outside of it will be infected

Comment: See this book problem #34 
https://books.google.com/books?id=ButlynVk25MC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=spread&f=false . The answer is in the back. It's nearly the same problem. Old book by Bela Bolobas.

Comment: @Cooperation: I recommend reverting back to a title that at least partially explains the puzzle. Uninformative titles like "STOPPING THE CORONAVIRUS" aren't helpful to those browsing the questions list, or to those doing a site search for this or related questions. (If nothing else, please remove the ALL CAPS, as this is considered SHOUTING.)

Comment: @Blueb "Virus spreading over square grid"?

Comment: @user: See the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3941773/revisions) for my suggestion.

Comment: They should have said "contaminated by *covid-2020*". They broke the theme of using the current year wherever an arbitrary number is required!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does there exist an initial arrangement of 10 black squares such that all the squares will ultimately be black?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490115/does-there-exist-an-initial-arrangement-of-10-black-squares-such-that-all-the-sq)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Claim: On an $n$ by $n$ grid, if there are fewer than $n$ squares initially infected, then the infection will not spread to the entire region.

Define a edge of a square to be a *frontier edge* if one side of the edge is infected but the other side is uninfected. (The region outside the entire $n$ by $n$ grid is considered to always be uninfected.)

Key lemma: As the infection propagates, the number of frontier edges can never increase.

Proof of key lemma: Whenever the infection spreads to a new square, then at least two of its neighbors was already infected, hence you lose at least two frontier edges and gain at most two. End of proof.

Proof of claim: Suppose the infection spreads to the entire region. At that time, the number of frontier edges is $4n$ (the entire outer edge of the board). By the key lemma, the number of initial frontier edges must be at least $4n$. Therefore, there must have been at least $n$ initial squares infected.  Put another way, if there were fewer than $n$ squares initially infected, then the infection will not propagate to the entire region.

(By the way, there are many initial configurations of size $n$ that lead to the whole board becoming infected, not just the diagonals.)